# keras run validation after every N training epochs

Tags: validation, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using the following function to train/validate my model:

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=2, workers=12)
```

The above function runs validation every epoch. My validation data is quite large so I want to run it every N epochs instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like that keras has updated their fit/fit_generator with a new input argument `validation_freq` which can be used to set how frequent the validation data is evaluated. According to the doc (as of version 2.2.4):

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1)
fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1, class_weight=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0)
```

Comment: In case you're using TensorFlow: Keras 2.2.4 is part of TensorFlow r1.14.